# Как изменить состояние во вложенном объекте || Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Мне нужно изменить состояние значения category:

```
const initialState = {
    filterState: {
        category: "All",
        search: ""
    },
    postState: {
        posts: [],
        counter: 5
    }
}
```

Не понимаю как изменить состояние во вложенном объекте, пробовал так

```
filterState.category: action.payload
```

Это не работает. Помогите

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробывать)

```
return {...initialState, filterState: {...initialState.filterState, category: 'hello'}}
```